# Is there a way to set a background image on an img tag that doesn't have an id in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image within a header 3 tag and I have a jquery function that expands and collapses the table. I need to change the expand / collapse icon when the function is done, which I can do. My question is can I change the image that is within the h3 tag even if it doesn't have an id?

So something like:

```
$(this.img).css("backgroundImage", "url(images/expand.png)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('h3').find('img').attr('src', 'url(images/expand.png)')
```

Or since you have a reference within the toggle:

```
$(this).find('img').attr('src', 'url(images/expand.png)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the CSS instead of changing the src of the image? Try
`$("img", this).attr("src", "images/expand.png");`

Comment: Sorry, I figured that out after I posted this, but I'm still wondering about the no-id part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.You have a typo. `backgroundImage` should be `background-image` like this:

```
$(this.img).css("background-image", "url(images/expand.png)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure..

```
$('h3 img').css(/* --- */);
```

Just don't use `.img` because that is for a css class called "img".

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

```
$(this).animate({'height':'toggle'},function(){$(this).find('img').attr('src','pathtoimage.png');})
```